# Unexpected warnings in Xilinx

Tags: verilog, xilinx

In the following code, I am storing the history of buttons player 1 and player 2 pressed. The code compiles without errors but has warnings. I am unable to solve these warnings. I am posting the code here.

```
module game(clk50,red,green,blue,hsync,vsync, button,led);

input [8:0] button;
 input clk50;
 output  red;
 output  green;
 output  blue,led;
 output hsync;
 output vsync;
 // divide input clock by two, and use a global 
// clock buffer for the derived clock
reg clk25_int;
always @(posedge clk50) begin
clk25_int <= ~clk25_int;
end
wire clk25;
BUFG bufg_inst(clk25, clk25_int);
wire [9:0] xpos;
wire [9:0] ypos;

Grid_Display Grid_Displayinst(clk25,xpos, ypos, red, green, blue, button,led);

endmodule

module Grid_Display(clk25,xpos,ypos,red,green,blue, button,led);

 input clk25;
 input [9:0] xpos;//responsible for current pixel display location
 input [9:0] ypos;// responsible for current display row

 input [8:0] button;

 //spartan 3 kit has 3-bits per pixel, so 2^3 means 8 colours can be selected.

 output red; // colour 1
 output green; // colour 2
 output blue; // colur 3
 output led;

 //reg tempRed,tempGreen,tempBlue, GridRed,GridGreen,GridBlue;

 reg player1,player2;

 reg [8:0] player1History=0,player2History=0;


 wire grid = ((xpos >= 4 && xpos <= 799 &&  ypos >= 160 && ypos <= 165) || 
              (xpos >= 4 && xpos <= 790 &&  ypos >= 310 && ypos <= 315) ||
              (xpos >= 200 && xpos <= 205 &&  ypos >= 0 && ypos <= 520) || 
              (xpos >= 440 && xpos <= 445 &&  ypos >= 0 && ypos <= 520));



always @(posedge clk25)
begin

  player1History=  button ^ player2History;
  player2History=  button ^ player1History;

  player1 = ((player1History[0] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120) ) || (player1History[1] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120))
          || (player1History[2] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120)) || (player1History[3] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 180 && ypos  <=280))
          || (player1History[4] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 180 && ypos <=280)) || (player1History[5] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 180 && ypos <=280))
          || (player1History[6] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430)) || (player1History[7] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430))
          || (player1History[8] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430)));

  player2 = ((player2History[0] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120) ) || (player2History[1] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120))
          || (player2History[2] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 20 && ypos <=120)) || (player2History[3] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 180 && ypos <=280))
          || (player2History[4] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 180 && ypos <=280)) || (player2History[5] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 180 && ypos <=280))
          || (player2History[6] && (xpos >=50 && xpos<=150 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430)) || (player2History[7] && (xpos >=250 && xpos<=350 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430))
          || (player2History[8] && (xpos >=490 && xpos<=590 && ypos >= 330 && ypos <=430)));

end 

 assign red = (grid || player1 );
 assign green = (grid || player2);
 assign blue = (grid );

endmodule
```

How can I solve these warnings?

```
WARNING:Xst:2211 - "grid.v" line 104: Instantiating black box module <dummyModule>.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <player2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_2> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_3> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_4> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_5> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_6> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_7> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <player2History_8> has a constant value of 0 in block <Grid_Display>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:2036 - Inserting OBUF on port <led> driven by black box <dummyModule>. Possible simulation mismatch.
```

Regards

Comment: -1 for dumping a ton of code and compiler output on us without showing your own fair effort. Please narrow down your question to the smallest example that reproduces your issue. Be VETSMOD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your warnings about FF/Latch trimming basically boil down to the issue that player2History is always 0, and as such it is being optimized out.

It wouldn't look like it should always be 0, but it turns out to be true due to an interesting side effect of the fact that you used the wrong type of blocking statements.

The issue is in these two lines in your always block:

```
always @(posedge clk25) begin
 player1History=  button ^ player2History;
 player2History=  button ^ player1History;
```

Your logic then evaluates like this:

1. At beginning of time player2History (p2h) is zero.
2. On some posedge of the clock, assume button is nonzero. At this point p2h is still zero, so `p1h = button ^ 0` just means that p1h gets assigned the value of button.
3. Now the next statement is evaluated, and you're evaluating `button ^ p1h`, but since we just assigned `p1h = button`, you're really evaluating `button ^ button`, which we know is always 0.
4. Since it's not possible in this case for p2h to ever be non-zero, the flops were removed from your design.

What you probably **meant** to do was to make p1h and p2h **non-** blocking assignments, with the `<=` operator. When you use nonblocking it means that both statements are evaulated in parallel, so both p1h and p2h are evaluated against their old values, instead of first computing the first line, and then using this result in the second line.

Understanding the difference between blocking and non-blocking statements is very important in verilog, and if you don't understand the concept or when to use them, then you should seek additional training materials.