# Xilinx warnings (FF/Latch trimming) in Verilog for a MSB downsampling

Tags: debugging, warnings, verilog, sampling

In [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106186/resampling-with-msb-operation/) other question I asked I got some general advice regarding my module.
Now I seek advice here since I noted that the Verilog community has more users.

I am trying to implement into an existing framework a Most Significant Bit (MSB) operation.
The idea is as follows: I am getting 32 bit complex samples in from `ddc_out_strobe`, which are 16 bit I and 16 bit Q.
My idea is to combine 4 "cutted" samples into a new sample to feed to the output `bb_sample`. This is done by getting the 4 MSB out of I0,Q0,I1,Q1,I2,Q2,I3,Q3 (4*8 = 32 bit total) and wiring them every 4th `bb_strobe` to `bb_sample`.

Here you can see my implementation:

```
module my_rx_dsp0_custom
#(
    //frontend bus width
    parameter WIDTH = 24
)
(
    //control signals
    input clock, //dsp clock
    input reset, //active high synchronous reset
    input clear, //active high on packet control init
    input enable, //active high when streaming enabled

    //user settings bus, controlled through user setting regs API
    input set_stb, input [7:0] set_addr, input [31:0] set_data,

    //full rate inputs directly from the RX frontend
    input [WIDTH-1:0] frontend_i,
    input [WIDTH-1:0] frontend_q,

    //full rate outputs directly to the DDC chain
    output [WIDTH-1:0] ddc_in_i,
    output [WIDTH-1:0] ddc_in_q,

    //strobed samples {I16,Q16} from the RX DDC chain
    input [31:0] ddc_out_sample,
    input ddc_out_strobe, //high on valid sample
    output ddc_out_enable, //enables DDC module

    //strobbed baseband samples {I16,Q16} from this module
    output [31:0] bb_sample,
    output bb_strobe //high on valid sample
);

    reg [3:0] i_msb;
    reg [3:0] q_msb;

    reg [31:0]temp_buff = 0;
    reg [31:0]my_zeros = 0;
    reg [1:0] count = 0;

    always @(posedge clock) 
        if(ddc_out_strobe) begin
            i_msb <= ddc_out_sample[31:28];
            q_msb <= ddc_out_sample[15:12];
            temp_buff <= {i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31:24]};
            // to avoid if-else conditions
            count <= (count==2'd3) ? 2'd0 : (count+1);
        end

    // to avoid if-else conditions
    assign bb_strobe = (count==2'd3) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0; 

    assign bb_sample = (count==2'd3) ? temp_buff : my_zeros;    
    assign ddc_out_enable = enable;
    assign ddc_in_i = frontend_i;
    assign ddc_in_q = frontend_q;   

endmodule //my_rx_dsp0_custom
```

**(1)** When trying to build the FPGA images I get the following warning (I just show you the one for `23`, but it is the same for other ones):

```
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <temp_buff_23> has a constant value of 0 in block <my_rx_dsp0_custom>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process
```

I have searched this problem in SE and found some good explanations on what might be going wrong, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556752/unexpected-warnings-in-xilinx?answertab=votes#tab-top) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702388/warnings-while-running-code-in-xilinx) for example.
What I understand is the following: `temp_buff <= {i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31:24]};` is a conflictive line since the `<=` operator is getting the **old** values from `i_msb` and `q_msb`, and not the ones from the MSB operation.

**(2)** I tried avoiding `if-else` conditions to allow me to declare some things out of the `always @*` block (this way I avoid having a wire on the LHS of an `always` block, which is not allowed).

Are my conditionals correct?
As I explained before, I want only every 4th `bb_sample` to be assigned.
Is `assign bb_strobe = (count==2'd3) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;` getting the effect I want despite not being in the `always @(posedge clock)` block?

*If other infos are needed, please let me know. This is part of a much bigger project that I am trying to modify for my purposes.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** The trimmed FF/Latch warning is not due to non-blocking assignments. It is from 24 bits of the `temp_buff` register always being assigned to zeros. The RHS is 16bits; `i_msb` (4 bits), `q_msb` (4 bits), and `temp_buff[31:24]` (8 bits). And you are assigning it to a 32bit value. The assignment:

```
temp_buff <= {i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31:24]};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
temp_buff <= {16'h0000, i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31:24]};
```

This means `temp_buff[31:16]` will always be zero can can be optimized out. `temp_buff[7:0]` can also be optimized out to constant zeros because it is assigned to `temp_buff[31:24]` which is a constant 0. Perhaps you meant you shift right 8 bits like so:

```
temp_buff <= {i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31: 8 ]};
```

**(2)** You are correct that wires should not be assigned with any always block (or initial block). However you could have turned the `wire` to a `reg`. It is a miss conception that `reg` is for registers only (FF/Latches). `reg` in a *properly* coded combinational block will create combinational logic (no FF or Latches). *Property* meaning the `reg` is assigned within every branching condition withing the always block, else it infers a latch. Example

```
module my_rx_dsp0_custom
/* ... your original code ... */
    output reg [31:0] bb_sample,
    output reg bb_strobe //high on valid sample
);
/* ... your original code ... */
    always @(posedge clock) 
        if(ddc_out_strobe) begin
            temp_buff <= {i_msb,q_msb,temp_buff[31:8]};
            count <= (count==2'd3) ? 2'd0 : (count+1);
        end

    always @*
        begin
            i_msb = ddc_out_sample[31:28];
            q_msb = ddc_out_sample[15:12];
            bb_strobe = (count==2'd3); 
            bb_sample = bb_strobe ? temp_buff : 32'd0;  
        end

    assign ddc_out_enable = enable;
/* ... your original code ... */
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, really helpful!
**(2)** Am I allowed to declare `bb_sample` and `bb_strobe` as `reg` even if in other modules where this one is called they are defined as `wire`s?

Comment: @user17247, yes `reg` & `wire` are **not** types that are inherited they only apply to the current module. `output reg a`, has to drive a wire (conectivity) at the next level.